# Dokku zero downtime deploy CHECKS fails

Tags: deployment, docker, dokku

Started to work with the Zero downtime deploy in Dokku and it fails to check the CHECKS file.

CHECKS file content, `/home/dokku/oktob/CHECKS`

```
WAIT=30     # Wait 1/2 minute
TIMEOUT=60  # Timeout after a minute
ATTEMPTS=10  # attempt checks 10 times

/pages/about info@oktob.io
/assets/twitter-f5f5e668ebe5e0324b1cc9f568d47e2d.jpg
```

The App is running at [178.62.102.155](http://178.62.102.155/), the first path is the [about page](http://178.62.102.155/pages/about) and the second is an [image](http://178.62.102.155/assets/twitter-f5f5e668ebe5e0324b1cc9f568d47e2d.jpg)

This is the deployment failure message

```
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Releasing oktob...
-----> Deploying oktob...
-----> Checking status of PostgreSQL
       Found image postgresql/oktob database
       Checking status... ok.
-----> Running pre-flight checks
Waiting 5 seconds ...
checking with: curl -q --compressed --fail --location --max-time 30 http://172.17.1.167:5000WAIT=30
remote:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
remote:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
remote:   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 172.17.1.167:5000WAIT=30
remote: /usr/local/bin/dokku: line 42: 21380 Killed                  dokku deploy "$APP"
To dokku@178.62.102.155:oktob
 ! [remote rejected] zero-downtime-deploy -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@178.62.102.155:oktob'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the CHECKS file inside the Rails app root and it works.